# How do I make `python setup.py test -q` quieter?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

I've just started a Pyramid project, following the recommendations from the [Pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html).

The command for testing looks like this:

```
../bin/python setup.py test -q
```

..which gives me this result:

```
$ ../bin/python setup.py test -q
running test
running egg_info
writing requirements to climas_ng.egg-info/requires.txt
writing climas_ng.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to climas_ng.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to climas_ng.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to climas_ng.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'climas_ng.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'climasng'
warning: no files found matching '*.mak' under directory 'climasng'
warning: no files found matching '*.mako' under directory 'climasng'
warning: no files found matching '*.xml' under directory 'climasng'
writing manifest file 'climas_ng.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.629s

OK
$
```

That's very wordy.  Is there a way to run my unit tests that doesn't tell me all the reading and writing and (AFAICT) irrelevant warnings?

Ideally I'd like output more like this:

```
$ ../bin/python setup.py test -q
running test
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.629s

OK
$
```

I've looked at `setup.py` and the `test` task isn't defined there, I guess it's baked into setuptools.

The `-q` quiet option I'm already using switches from one-full-line-per-test to one-dot-per-test, which is great, but doesn't quieten the other noise.  There's no `-Q` or `-qq` for "very quiet".

Am I missing something?  Or do I just have to get used to 15 lines of useless info before the good stuff appears.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The position of arguments is important here. Move the `-q` switch back a bit:

```
python setup.py -q test
```

This makes the switch a global one, and suppresses the build output. Any switches for the tests must come after the `test` command.

Comment: Thanks!  I still get the warning lines, but that's just five lines of noise to skim over.